# Add temporary additonal Memory Logger on nlog

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I have nlog configuration working fine on a C# program.
the nlog config is done via standalone file nlog.config
In a specific part of the code I want however to create an additional memory logger target in order to save this specific part of logs in a buffer ( i will later attach this  buffer to a specific object in the  database).

To do so i try to add programmatically the logger and its config.
I check that the logger is added and the rule is added, however nothing comes to the newly created logger.
I think i miss something to tell nlog to actually take in consideration the new logger .
once the target function is executed i want to stop to log this piece of code, stil use the other loggers, and do the same thing on a next item.

I add the memory logger with this lines of code:

```
                MemoryTarget memoryLogger = new MemoryTarget("memoryTarget");
                memoryLogger.Layout = "${message}";
                LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(memoryLogger);
                LogManager.Configuration.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, memoryLogger);
```

below you see the nlog config before i add the new logger:
[image: config before]

below the config after the new logger is added:

- LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules has a new element
- LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets has a new element
  however in the details of the target i see:
- IsInitialized to false
- Loging config to null ( while i added the rule to LogManager.Configuration
- the 'Logs' property which should contains all the lines logged is empty

I do not want to reinitialise all the nlog since it would reset my logfile, and i want a new log file at each process startup.

[image: config after]

Comment: After having completed updating `Configuration.LoggingRules` then one should call `LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers()` to "commit" the changes (Update the already created Logger-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Rolf Kristensen,

indeed,

```
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

Permits to initialize the memory logger without resetting my other logger on File.
By doing this the ConfigurationChanged/ConfigurationReloaded static events of LogManager are even not trigerred, and it works nicely! Great !

Final code to activate and desactivate temporarily the logs in memory:

```
                MemoryTarget memoryTarget = new MemoryTarget("memoryTarget");
                memoryTarget.Layout = "${message}";
                LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(memoryTarget);
                var memoryRule = new LoggingRule("memoryRule");
                memoryRule.EnableLoggingForLevels(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal);
                memoryRule.Targets.Add(memoryTarget);
                memoryRule.LoggerNamePattern = "*";
                LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(memoryRule);
                LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
                _log.Debug("this is dumped in memory");
                foreach (string s in memoryTarget.Logs)
                {
                    Console.Write("---------mem dumped: {0}", s);
                }
                LogManager.Configuration.RemoveTarget(memoryTarget.Name);
                bool removed = LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Remove(memoryRule);
                LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
                _log.Debug("no more in memory");
```

Comment: Notice you can use NLog Layout logic inside logging-rules, so they can be activated on-demand. So you can have targets and logging-rules configured, and then just flip a [GDC](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer) or NLog-Config-variable to either enable or disable the targets. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages#semi-dynamic-routing-rules

Answer (score 0):

If you read this post, you might be interested to grab this piece of code:

```
    public class MemoryLogger
    {
        static Logger _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        MemoryTarget _memoryTarget;
        LoggingRule _memoryRule;

        public void Start()
        {
            _memoryTarget = new MemoryTarget("memoryTarget");
            _memoryTarget.Layout = "${message}";
            LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(_memoryTarget);
            _memoryRule = new LoggingRule("memoryRule");
            _memoryRule.EnableLoggingForLevels(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal);
            _memoryRule.Targets.Add(_memoryTarget);
            _memoryRule.LoggerNamePattern = "*";
            LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(_memoryRule);
            LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
        }

        public StringBuilder Stop()
        {
            LogManager.Configuration.RemoveTarget(_memoryTarget.Name);
            bool removed = LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Remove(_memoryRule);
            if (!removed)
                _log.Error("cannot remove rule "+_memoryRule.RuleName);
            LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
            var ret = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string s in _memoryTarget.Logs)
            {
                ret.AppendLine(s);
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
```